# Firing UILocalNotification on specific days only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I have an application where I need to fire a notification on certain days of the week only (defined by the user).  I've used local notifications before but its always been fairly straight-forward, everyday, week etc at the same time.  However I've never had to fire the same notification, at the same time, on specific days only.  Has anyone done this before and can shed some light on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What i normally do is make one notification for each day needed and have it on a weekly repeat cycle.

Then just enable / disable the appropriate days